# Philippians 2:12 why “with fear?”

Tags: contradiction, philippians

Soon after the beautiful declaration concerning the salvation of all mankind in Phil. 2:10-11 Paul exhorts the church

> So then, my beloved, even as you have always obeyed, not only in my
>   presence, but now much more in my absence, work out your own salvation
>   with **fear** and trembling. (Phil. 2:12)

This confounds me that God wants us to be in fear and trembling as we work out going through the process of being conformed to His image. The word used is [φόβος (fob-os) “from a primary phebomai (to be put in fear); alarm or fright: be afraid, + exceedingly, fear, terror.”](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?t=kjv&strongs=g5401) The same word is used in 1 John 1:4-18:

> There is no **fear** in love; but perfect love casts out **fear**, because
>   **fear** has punishment. He who **fears** is not made perfect in love.

Here John tells us ...perfect love casts out fear and... he who fears has not yet been perfected by love.

These verses appear to contradict one another. I looked at the preposition “with” being used and it seems to me the use of “against” is allowable. I’m not really well versed in the rules of grammar but can anyone tell me why “against”, which resolves the contradiction, cannot or should not be used instead of “with?”

By using “against” the following verse 2:13 “For it is God who works in you both to will and to work, for his good pleasure.” makes much more sense to me. Your thoughts and corrections are welcome if I have misconstrued this passage.

Comment: Hi Merks, welcome to BHSE! Please take the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) when you get a chance, which explains a bit more about the StackExchange format and what kind of Questions we deal with here. I've flagged this question as a possible duplicate above, and so if this has already been answered elsewhere then we will move to Close this Question.

Answer (score 2):

The preposition *meta* is translated not only as ‘with’, but more accurately as ‘among’ or ‘amid’. It isn’t so much a physical positioning alongside, but rather ‘in company with’ as a collective sense.

Paul seems to be acknowledging the Philippians’ fear and doubt upon hearing of his imprisonment, and encouraging them to continue their work *amid* this fear - to not let their fear keep them from working towards this salvation for themselves.

The following verse 2:13 reassures them that God works in them amid this fear, “to will and to work for His good pleasure”.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It makes very good sense to me since you associate fear and trembling as a response to Paul’s imprisonment. It also gives force to the confidence one receives from verse 13 and it seems to harmonize with 1 John 4:18. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to be said is what Philippians 2:12 does not say? It is not advocating to work out your salvation to get saved or to stay saved. The context is extremely important starting at verse 1 through verse 12.

I'm going to paraphrase what's going on here. At verse 2-3, the Apostle Paul is telling the Philippian "BELIEVERS" to have the same mind, maintaining the same love and be united in purpose. Do not be selfish or conceited and regard other people more important than yourself.

Verse 4, Do not look out for your own personal interest but put the interest in others first. At verse 5,6, 7, Have the same attitude which was also in Christ Jesus, who, (always existing in the form of God), emptied or veiled the prerogatives/glory He had before the world was. John 17:5.

Verse 8, And being found in appearance as a man He humbled Himself by being obedient to the point of death, even death on a cross. At verse 12, the first two words are "So then," which means, since the above is true, work out your own salvation with fear and trembling. In other words, "WORK OUT THE SOLUTION OF YOUR PROBLEMS" of not being selfish, conceited and not putting others first etc."  Why? Verse 13, "for (or because) it is God who is at work in your both to will and to work for His good pleasure."

And to expand on this verse 14, "Do all things without grumbling or disputing; verse 15, that you may prove yourselves to be blameless and innocent, children of God above reproach etc. I think the "fear and trembling" warning means, "Don't give God a hard time."

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I do understand there is work involved in the believers walk. It’s the with fear and trembling part The is getting me hung up. I know God is to be revered and I am truly in awe of Him but I don’t feel He wants be to be afraid of potential retribution or punishment. Correction? Yes? Punishment? No. I tend to agree with the first poster the word amid or among is more in keeping with the character of this epistle. Blessings, Merks

Comment: @Merks Maybe the following verse will ease your concerns. 1 John 4:18, "There is no fear in love; BUT PERFECT LOVE CAST OUT FEAR, because (or why?), fear involves punishment, and the one who fears is not perfected in love." Verse 19, "We love, because He first loved us." We as Christians need not fear God as those who don't personally know Him. Sure, as Christians we still sin but here at 1 John 2:1, "My little children, I am writing these things to you that you man not sin. And if anyone sins, we have an Advocate with the Father, Jesus Christ the righteous:"And you should be in "awe" of Him.

Comment: Thank you my brother and that is precisely why I posed my question. If I continued to operate under the kind of fear some would have me listen to I would most certainly become an insane son. I am persuaded His love form me never increases nor does it lesson based on my performance but is firmly rooted in the work of Christ on my behalf and on behalf of ALL MANKIND. Blessings to you and those you love for your encouragement in His Word. Merks

Answer (score 1):

We may have to concern ourselves here with the word “salvation” and the particular meaning. It is always good when discussing theological issues to gain clarity by asking, “what do you mean by…?” We often project our assumptions onto what others are saying.

In the western churches – especially Evangelical – the tendency is to view “salvation” as a line to cross.  Did you pray the prayer? Did you accept Jesus as your personal Lord and Savior? Then you are “saved.”

On the Eastern side of Christianity, they have a different view of salvation. For them, salvation is a process that you engage in over your lifetime to transform yourself to be more and more like Christ. See 2 Peter 1:4.  The west uses the term sanctification.

Eastern Churches use the word [Theosis or Deification](https://ww1.antiochian.org/content/theosis-partaking-divine-nature) – which really bothers many westerners – because they misinterpret it to mean that you “become a god” yourself. That is incorrect. It is the process of becoming “like Christ” partaking in the divine nature. Becoming what God intended you to be – through the grace and power of Jesus Christ.

The “fear and trembling” which Paul speaks of comes through having to transform ourselves. God will provide the power to do it – but you must choose to walk that path. Authentic spiritual growth – also called Spiritual Formation – is difficult and takes courage.

Authentic growth calls us to face the reality of who we are and to shed or heal those areas of our life which are holding us back. Other biblical ways of describing this are “to separate the wheat from the chaff” – the chaff being those parts of you that are not serving you well and must be judged. Also, both Paul and Peter speak of dying to self – or having died to self in Christ. Spiritual growth – as a metaphor – is a “death-resurrection” cycle. You transform yourself by descending to the depths of who you are – judging that which needs judging – and emerging “renewed.”

If you’ve experienced authentic spiritual growth you can feel this process in action. I can only describe the outcome as “expansion” – that I what it feels like.  You see yourself more firmly as a child of God and “fear” is ultimately cast out.

In this passage, Paul is writing to those in Philippi - a Roman Colony. If you are going to move from being a pagan to a Christian - or Roman citizen who becomes a Christian - you are going to have to make major changes to your worldview. You will lose friends or family. Maybe even your job. It is going to take courage to "be transformed by the renewing of your mind" (Romans 12:2). You are going to have to challenge many of the beliefs you once held as "true."

There are many excellent books on Spiritual Growth or those, like St. John of the Cross, who were great spiritualists. One that I would recommend is *[The Critical Journey](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1879215497)* – by Hagberg and Guelich. In this book, they discuss what they call “The wall.” “The Wall” is that which we all must face in our lives that we don’t really want to face. You can’t get around it – you must go through it – and that takes courage.  “The Wall” stops many people from growing. They find the journey too difficult.

St. John of the Cross refers to the things which hinder us as “attachments.”

“working out your Salvation” in this sense is having the courage to release those “attachments” and see the world closer to the way God sees the world.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I appreciate your thoughts and enjoyed the idea of busting through the wall rather than going around. I know the walk of faith is not easy but love covers a multitude of sins and we are encouraged to come boldly before the throne of Grace because verse 13 gives us this confidence. Also, thanks for the book reference The Critical Journey, I may indeed give this a read. Blessings, Merks

Answer (score 0):

The operative word here is φόβου (phobou) from the root noun φόβος (phobos).  BDAG lists several meanings for this word:

1. Intimidating entity: (a) *intimidation*, eg, 1 Peter 3:14.  (b) (concretely) *something terrible/awe-inspiring, a terror*, eg, Rom 13:3, 2 Cor 5:11.
2. The product of an intimidating/alarming force: (a) *fear, alarm, fright*, eg, 1 Cor 7:11, 1 Peter 1:17, 1 Cor 2:3, 2 Cor 7:15, etc.  (b) *reverence*, *respect*, eg, Phil 2:12, Rom 3:18, 13:7, 2 Cor 7:1, Acts 9:31, 2 Cor 5:11, Eph 5:21, 6:5, 1 Peter 2:18, 3:2, etc.

It is significant that BDAG attributes the meaning (2b) in Phil 2:12; that is reverence or respect.

> The Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges comments on this verse by
>   saying, with fear and trembling] not of tormenting misgiving (cp. 1
>   John 4:18), but of profound reverence and wakeful conscience. So 1
>   Corinthians 2:3; 2 Corinthians 7:15; Ephesians 6:5.

Matthew Poole observes on this verse:

> With fear and trembling; i.e. with a holy care to do all acceptably:
>   he doth by these two words mean not any servile fear and slavish
>   despondency, arising from doubting, Philippians 4:4, but only a
>   serious, filial fear, implying a deep humility and submissiveness of
>   mind, with a reverential awe of the Divine Majesty, and a solicitude
>   to avoid that evil which is offensive to him and separates from him.
>   We find these words used to the like import, Psalm 2:11 Daniel 5:19
>   Daniel 6:26 Romans 11:20 with 1 Corinthians 2:3 2 Corinthians 7:5
>   Ephesians 6:5;

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It appears to me that reverence and awe can also be derived from the word used in verse 12 and verse 13 can still be an encouragement to strengthen verse 12 but the reply above seems (at least to me) to be one which takes into account the imprisonment of Paul and the supports the overall character of Paul’s letter to the church. It also seems to harmonize better with 1 John 4:18. Thank you again for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

He means to fear God, who will judge you, ***thereby avoiding*** the judgement of those who live wickedly: for with God there is no partiality—in fact, there is greater judgement for someone given the gift of salvation, but who "in time of trial, fall away" (Luke 8:13). 2 Peter 2:20.

> **Revelation 14:7** Saying with a loud voice: Fear the Lord, and give him honour, because the hour of his judgment is come; and adore ye him, that made heaven and earth, the sea, and the fountains of waters.
>
> **2 Corinthians 5:9-10** And therefore we labour, whether absent or present, to please him. For we must all be manifested before the judgment seat of Christ, that every one may receive for the things done in the body, **whether it be good or evil.**

That is, fear is given as the protection against judgement, not as the means to obtain it, but to avoid not receiving salvation. After all, a disobeyer of God is incompatible with the image of Christ, incompatible with heaven.

---

> **2 Peter 3:10-16** But the day of the Lord **shall come as a thief,** in which the heavens shall pass away with great violence, and the elements shall be melted with heat, and the earth and the works which are in it, shall be burnt up.
>
> Seeing then that all these things are to be dissolved, **what manner of people ought you to be in holy conversation and godliness?** 12 Looking for and hasting unto the coming of the day of the Lord, by which the heavens being on fire shall be dissolved, and the elements shall melt with the burning heat? 13 But we look for new heavens and a new earth according to his promises, in which justice dwelleth. 14 **Wherefore, dearly beloved, waiting for these things, be diligent that you may be found before him unspotted and blameless in peace.** 15 And account the longsuffering of our Lord, salvation; **as also our most dear brother Paul, according to the wisdom given him, hath written to you:** 16 As also in all his epistles, **speaking in them of these things; in which are certain things hard to be understood, which the unlearned and unstable wrest, as they do also the other scriptures, to their own destruction.**

Therefore there is no contradiction between describing the glory of salvation, and describing the need to avoid losing it by not watching for the Master's return, not using your "talents," basically not living as a Christian, but as if you weren't one, which is the constant warning of St. Paul, who even took care that he himself didn't lose his inheritance:

> **1 Corinthians 9:27** But I chastise my body, and bring it into subjection: lest perhaps, when I have preached to others, **I myself** should become a castaway.

As for "fear" being at odds with love, in this context of John's Epistle, fear seems to refer to a lack of hope, and not to fear of the Lord, which every man should do. If you don't "fear him who can destroy" in hell, then you aren't obeying Jesus:

> **Matthew 10:28** And fear ye not them that kill the body, and are not able to kill the soul: **but rather fear him** that can destroy both soul and body in hell.

Jesus warns believers to remove persistent sins/occasions of sin in their lives, which alludes to the same concept of "fear" St. Paul mentions:

> **Matthew 5:30** And if thy right hand scandalize thee, cut it off, and cast it from thee: for **it is expedient for thee** that one of thy members should perish, rather than that thy whole body be cast **into hell.**

---

Translating "meta" as "against" is against the context:

> So then, my beloved, even as you have always obeyed ... work out your own salvation with fear and trembling

The part "not only while I'm with you, but all the more when I'm gone," is subservient and supplementary data in this sentence; and "work out your salvation against fear and trembling" makes no sense: why would you admonish them to obey, and then say there is no fear in not doing so? 'You have always obeyed with fear and trembling' is the syntactically necessary understanding of the verse: St. Paul merely telling them to 'keep up the good work.'

Comment: Thanks for posting your reply. I simply do not think this is what the Apostle had in mind when he penned this verse. One’s interpretation cannot be excluded from one’s view of God and I find yours to be too weighted in fear. Not stating you are wrong but just not where I am at in my walk with Christ.

Comment: One's interpretation should surely determine one's view of God. You don't bring pre-concieved doctrines to your interpretation, otherwise you are leading the Bible, not the other way around. I cite Jesus saying fear not men who can only kill the body, but fear God who can kill both body and soul in hell. Jesus said, "Fear God." He also taught, 'Get rid of things which cause you to sin - it's better for you, even if you lose out on these, than to go to hell having had them.' That's *pretty* explicit. That's good fear - fearing becoming a castaway, unfit for use by God - seed with no fruit.

Comment: I’m sorry if I offended you my friend. I do in fact fear God in a healthy way just as my dear children fear me with a healthy respect. But they are never in fear of retribution and my love for them reigns first in their understanding of my actions. Paul tells us that God has not given us the spirit of fear but of Love, peace and a sound mind. I accept His forgiveness and try to fulfill the law of love and seek to obey from the heart of the new creation he has and is making me to become. In His love and Grace ... Merks

Comment: You didn't offend me at all, and I'm sorry it came across that way. I just find it an entirely contrived and unnecessary contradiction. One can fear not persevering to the end, as a means to avoid not doing so. And not a pointless fear because you are, and intend to remain, a sinner. These are two different fears, one belies faithlessness, and one belies a faith which intends to do God's will.